# Compilation vs Execution in SAS

Tags: sas

This question was discussed on [SAS forum](https://communities.sas.com/message/203961), and participants finally agreed to disagree .

The issue is simple : SAS assign a `missing value` to all variables at compile time `UNLESS`  a variable shows up in a `sum statement` (in this case SAS assigns a value of `0` at compile time ) . Here is my simple proof

```
  data test;
  put _all_;
  var1+1;
  var2=5;
  put _all_;
  run;
```

---

Log screen

```
var1=0 var2=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
var1=1 var2=5 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 2 variables.
```

`var2` was assigned a `missing value` BUT `var1` was assigned `0` because it is part of a `sum statement` (I believe so )

---

My question is WHY ? I was pretty sure that SAS assignes `missing values` to all variables at compilation . Why does it make an exception to a variable that will show up in a `sum statement` ? Are there any other exceptions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't call it sum statement.

The statement

```
var1+1;
```

is equivalent of

```
retain var1 0;
var1 = var1 + 1;
```

Nor the 'long' sum statement

```
var1 = var1 + 1;
```

nor

```
var1 = sum(var1, 1);
```

itself would do the RETAIN behavior nor initialization to zero.
So to answer the question:

initialization to zero is part of RETAIN behavior implicitly requested by
`a + b;`
syntax for variable `a`.

I can't think of other exceptions.

Comment: Good explanation.  It's also worth noting that the whereabouts in the datastep you actually place the `retain` statement does not affect the timing of the when the statement is recognized.  So placing the retain statement as the last line of code is the same as placing it as the first line of code.